# App freezes/behaves strangely when opening FROM App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, behavior

We have an app on the App Store that is experiencing problems.

The app works fine through XCode, the app works fine when launched from the iPhone/iPad/iPod "dock" (the screens with all the apps, not sure what the official name is). However when trying to open the app straight from the App Store by pressing the "Open"-button, the app behaves strangely. **The behaviour is also different on different devices.**

We have 3 devices we can test on, an **iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 10.3.1** (also tested on 10.2.1), an **iPad Air 2 running 10.2.1** and an **iPod Touch Gen 5 running 9.3**.

**iPhone behaviour:** App opens then gets stuck at a black screen with an empty title bar.

**iPad behaviour:** App opens, skips the entire first tutorial view and continues to work as it should.

**iPod behaviour:** App works as it should.

The iPhone 7 Plus running 10.2.1 behaved exactly the same as when it's running 10.3.1.

I have tried finding more information about this problem but have so far been unable to. Have there been any other cases like this, and if so, is there a fix?

**UPDATE: I HAD THE CHANCE TO TEST THIS ON AN IPAD RUNNING 9.X, THERE WERE NO PROBLEMS, SO THIS SEEMS TO BE A 10.X ISSUE**

Comment: I have similar problem. App build for app store and ad hoc build behaves differently than when I install through xcode. Even if I run a release build which should be the same as ad hoc then it works properly when launched with xcode but when I build ad hoc it does not work which is very strange. Did not found what is causing the problem yet.

Comment: @LeszekS My problem ended up being the following. I pass the launchOptions from this function **-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions** to another function and then check whether it is nil or not. However when it launched from the App Store it wasn't nil, specifically the following key: **[[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey]  isEqual: @"com.apple.AppStore"]**. It was trying to run code for when the launchOptions aren't nil, when in fact they were, except for that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being the following. I pass the launchOptions from this function

- `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

to another function and then check whether it is nil or not. However when it launched from the App Store it wasn't nil, specifically the following key:

- `[[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey] isEqual: @"com.apple.AppStore"]`

It was trying to run code for when the launchOptions aren't nil, when in fact they were, except for that key.